# Discord.js messageCollector bug?

Tags: javascript, variables, discord, discord.js

i have a problem with the messageCollector

```
const msgFilter = (msg) => msg.author.id == message.author.id;
      const collector = message.channel.createMessageCollector(msgFilter);
      collector.on("collect", (msg) => {
        
        Health = 100

        if(msg.content === "punch") {
           Health -= 10 
        }
        console.log(Health)
```

when i type punch the result is 90
but when i type punch again the result is also 90, but it should be 80
I don't have this problem if i create the variable Health outside the messageCollector, but for my usage it must be inside of the messageCollector how can i make it, that every time i type punch 10 get removed?

It must be messagecollector and no other function, because it has to repeat every code inside the messagecollector

Comment: why should it be 80 when you are setting it to 100 every time on any message?

Comment: How should I do it to make it work

Comment: not sure what you want to achieve, its a health of what? globally server? or an user?

Comment: Its for an Fight-System There are enemys and the player and there are some Attacks i made an randomizer and the randomizer must be in the messagecollector, bcs every round the randomizer should select another attack ´
i took Health = 100 as an example
in my original code it is

chars[selected].Health -= chars[enemy].attacks[Attackresult].damage

and the Attackresult var is in the messageCollector, because every round the enemy makes a other attack

Answer (score 0):

A message collector doesn't take an argument of a filter; it takes an argument of MessageCollectorOptions, which includes the filter.
You would have to do something like this:

```js
 const collector = message.channel.createMessageCollector({
      filter: msgFilter
 });
```